# create-nuxt-app v5.0.0 + Tailwind UI Error - FATAL Cannot destructure property 'nuxt' of 'this' as it is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am unable to get create-nuxt-app v5.0.0 with Tailwind running.

Steps Ive already taken:

I tried to install node v 18.15.0
via NVM

I tried adding "@nuxt/kit": "3.2.3", to the package.json

I tried "overrides": {
"@nuxt/kit": "3.0.0-rc.12"
},

I tried "resolutions": {
"@nuxt/kit": "3.2.3"
},

I installed tailwind manually

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ nuxt

 WARN  The dependency stylelint not found. Please run yarn add stylelint --dev or npm install stylelint --save-dev

ℹ Using default Tailwind CSS file from runtime/tailwind.css  nuxt:tailwindcss 15:06:00

 FATAL  Cannot destructure property 'nuxt' of 'this' as it is undefined.      15:06:00

  at postcss8Module (node_modules/@nuxt/postcss8/dist/index.js:15:10)
  at installModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:451:21)
  at async setup (node_modules/@nuxtjs/tailwindcss/dist/module.mjs:186:7)
  at async ModuleContainer.normalizedModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:169:17)
  at async ModuleContainer.addModule (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:167:20)
  at async ModuleContainer.ready (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:34:7)
  at async Nuxt._init (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:342:5)

  ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                                 
                                                                         
      TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'nuxt' of 'this' as it is   
     undefined. 

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

I did get create-nuxt-app v5.0.0 working.

The key for me was not installing Tailwind during the initial create-nuxt-app installation process in the command line and instead following the directions at:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs

I do have node v 18.15.0 running as well.